# Mongoose Populate() like functionality in C# Mongo Driver

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose, we can populate reference document

My Document look like this,

```
var Menu = new Schema({
name: String,
items:[{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Items' }],
```

I have stored item document _id in Menu.Items.

So whenever i want to menu with items data, i do the following.

like

```
menu.findOne().populate( 'items').exec(function(err, menuData ) {
// here with menuData.items we can access referenced document. not just an _id
});
```

Q1. ) Is there any facility available in .Net C# MongoDb Driver?. 
Q2. ) How can i store reference of document ?

Thanks

Comment: i've been looking to do this too.  i'm afraid i need to manually query my sub-documents :(

Comment: I can make use of  "MongoDBRef". in my entity it will look like this

Comment: public MongoDBRef UserRef { get; set; } 
 
and whenever i want to access this 
i can do like this

    User userObj = db.FetchDBRefAs<User>(Post.UserRef);
 
So first i have to get post object and then i have to Fetch User Object.

Here i want list of MongoDBRef. But FetchDBRefAs comes with a single document only.

Anyone knows how to get whole list ?